# changing text view into list view

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine

I am using this [tutorial](http://www.giantflyingsaucer.com/blog/?p=1462) to make my android application . i want to show the response in listview instead of text view . on the server now i am retrieving some values which i want to show in the list which can be seen as http://mediasense4.appspot.com

The change up-till now i have made so far are

```
package com.giantflyingsaucer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AndroidHTTPClient extends ListActivity
{
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  RestClient client = new RestClient("http://mediasense4.appspot.com");

  setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, client));
  ListView lv = getListView();
  lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true); 


    }


}
```

but its giving me error on set list adapter which is "The constructor ArrayAdapter(AndroidHTTPClient, int, RestClient) is undefined"

I am not sure i am adding correctly or not . please help me out

from the server i am fetching response in way

```
PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
String query = "select from " + MediaSenseDb.class.getName() ;
List<MediaSenseDb> greetings = (List<MediaSenseDb>) pm.newQuery(query).execute();
if (greetings.isEmpty()) {

} else {
for (MediaSenseDb g : greetings) {


resp.getWriter().println( g.getDevice_key());
}
}
pm.close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not just pass any object you want into ArrayAdapter. It is expecting an Array of Strings and your passing it a RestClient so the adapters constructor does not know what to do with it.

What you need to do is parse your severs text response into a usable format (Array)

Comment: i have updated the question and added the server response for you .Any suggestion now ?

Comment: @user667340, it looks like sgarman's advice still applies.  The ArrayAdapter constructor doesn't take a RestClient.  The tutorial you referenced includes a more complete example of using RestClient to query the server and get the response data.  Take another look at its AndroidHTTPClient.